# Creating JSONObject from text file

Tags: java, android, json

I am attempting to read a text file and create a JSONObject in an Android application, but after reading the text file into a string, I get a JSONException thrown when I try to construct a JSONObject using the string.

Here is the code I am using:

```
InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.quiz);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)); 
    String jsString = "";
    String line = null;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        jsString += line;
    }
    is.close();
    reader.close();

    try {
        return new JSONObject(jsString);
    } catch (JSONException e) {

    }
    return null;
```

Here is the text file I am reading from, quiz.txt:

```
{"length":3,"questions":[{"questionText":"Is mayonaise an instrument?","answers":["Yes","no","no","no","no"],"correctAnswer":0},{"questionText":"10^2","answers":["1","10","100","1000","over 9000"],"correctAnswer":1},{"questionText":"Dogs Name?","answers":["Barky","Steve","Rex","Daisy","Wormy"],"correctAnswer":3}]}
```

Comment: Is there a message included in the exception (`e.getMessage()`)?

Comment: Have you tried to put your answers (the numbers) in quotes?

Comment: I checked the value of e.getMessage() and was able to find out where my issue lies. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method to read the file contents into a string.

```
 public static String getJsonFromResource( int resource, Context context ) {

        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource( resource );
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( inputStream ) );
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        String jsonString = null;
        try {
            while (( line = r.readLine() ) != null) {

                stringBuilder.append( line );
            }
            jsonString = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e( "GetJsonFromResource", Log.getStackTraceString( e ) );
        }
        return jsonString;
    }
```