# How to resolve The method toString() in the type Object is not applicable for the arguments (InputStream)

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to read a json file from my local machine.

```
@Path("/")
public class JsonParsing {

    File f = new File("file.json");
    if (f.exists()){
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("file.json");
        String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString(is);
        System.out.println(jsonTxt);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonTxt);       
        String a = json.getString("1000");
        System.out.println(a);   
    }

}
```

But I'm getting error in toString() method.
Also is it possible to read a .txt file containing json object from my local machine? If possible, how it is done?

Comment: The file ending does not matter. Just open your `file.txt` instead of `file.json`

Comment: Did you properly import `IOUtils` ?

Comment: what version of ioutils are you using?

Answer (score 3):

you may be using IOUtils and `import sun.misc.IOUtils` but the default does not include the method toString with parameter (InputStream) so you need to use apache common io lib to use this method and

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Firstly: whenever you ask the question- add imports as well.
Secondly: yes it is possible to read a .txt file containing json object.
Steps:
1. Add Maven dependency in your pom.xml -
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

Or add the jar of this dependency.

2.imports in java file -

import java.util.Iterator;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

3. Sample Java code to read .txt file containing 
this json object
{
    "Name": "crunchify.com",
    "Author": "App Shah",
    "Company List": [
        "Compnay: eBay",
        "Compnay: Paypal",
        "Compnay: Google"
    ]
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {

            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(
                    "/Users/<username>/Documents/file1.txt"));

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

            String name = (String) jsonObject.get("Name");
            String author = (String) jsonObject.get("Author");
            JSONArray companyList = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Company List");

            System.out.println("Name: " + name);
            System.out.println("Author: " + author);
            System.out.println("\nCompany List:");
            Iterator<String> iterator = companyList.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Hope it helps.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    File f = new File("file.json"); //it can be the same file "file.txt"
    InputStream is = null;
    if (f.exists()){
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream("file.json");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( is ) );
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        String jsString = null;
        try {
            while (( line = r.readLine() ) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append( line );
            }
            jsString = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(jsString); 
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsString);
        String a = jsonObj.getString("1000");
        System.out.println(a);   
    }
```

Refer to:
[Creating JSONObject from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443166/creating-jsonobject-from-text-file)